# Masking White areas of JPEG images

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas, alpha-transparency, image-masking

I want to mask a total White (R:255,G:255,B:255) areas in a JPEG image, so when viewed in the browser, in the total white areas I will see what underneath (those area will be transparent). I don't mind using JQuery, CSS 3 or Canvas, whatever works to achieve this. Thanks

OK, the code:

```
<body style="background-color:red;">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="228" height="454"></canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;
        var width = 228;
        var height = 454;
        var imageObj = new Image();

        imageObj.onload = function () 
        {
            context.drawImage(imageObj, x, y, width, height);

            var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
            var pixels = imgData.data; // get pixel data

            for (var i = 0; i < pixels.length; i +=4)
            {
                var r = pixels[i ];
                var g = pixels[i + 1]
                var b = pixels[i  + 2];

                if (r === 255 && g === 255 && b === 255) {
                    pixels[i + 3] = 1;
                }   
            }

            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
        };
        imageObj.src = 'img/test_image.jpg';
    </script>
  </body>
```

This code seems to do the job, but I get some scattered white dots in the area which is total white.

Comment: :) - definite answer?

Comment: Open them in photoshop, remove the areas, save as PNG.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: I put the code in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your code looks fairly correct, but I would suggest these changes:**

You set the canvas size to 228x454, but if your image is *slightly* different sized, you may be *accidentally scaling* the source image when you draw it to the canvas.  So, scale the canvas to exactly the image size:

```
imageObj.onload=function(){
canvas.width=imageObj.width;   // be sure canvas is *exactly* image sized to prevent 
canvas.height=imageObj.height; // accidental scaling which might skew pixel colors
```

You set the “transparent” pixels to 1 when you should set them to 0 for full transparency:

```
pixels[i+3]=0;      // 0 instead of 1 for pure transparency
```

You are only masking pure white--rgb(255,255,255).  It’s possible some of the pixels in your image are “nearly” white, so you might try masking some near-white pixels too.

```
var nearWhite=250;  // try experimenting with different “near white” values
if(r>nearWhite && g>nearWhite && b>nearWhite)
```

**[Edited: To provide complete code]**

Here is the code (works for me on my computer).

Be sure your image source is on your local domain, otherwise you will run into a **security violation** and the image will draw, but the white pixels will not be made transparent. So no http://otherDomain.com/picture.jpg!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function () {

        canvas.width=imageObj.width;
        canvas.height=imageObj.height;
        ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0,0);

        var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var pixels = imgData.data; // get pixel data
        for (var i = 0; i < pixels.length; i +=4)
        {
            var r = pixels[i ];
            var g = pixels[i + 1]
            var b = pixels[i  + 2];

            if (r>250 && g>250 && b>250) {
                pixels[i + 3] = 0;
                count++;
            }   
        }
        ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
    }
    imageObj.src="car.jpg";

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when I use canvas.width - imageObj.width (same for the height), it doesn't clear the white pixels anymore, image stays the same, any idea why (wen I remove those lines it removes them again)

Comment: I posted full code that works for me.  **Be sure your image source is on your local domain**, otherwise you will run into a security violation and the image will draw, but the white pixels will not be made transparent. So this will not work: http://otherDomain.com/picture.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Maybe create a canvas and populate the pixel values with the corrosponding ones from the image. If a pixel is white `rgb(255,255,255)` set the alpha to 1. Not sure if this is possible, just an idea.

[Tutorial for pixel manipulation](http://beej.us/blog/data/html5s-canvas-2-pixel/)

Comment: looks like an interesting lead!

Comment: That would be incredibly processor intensive? Seriously, just save the image as a .PNG with transparencies. the words "re-invent" and "wheel" spring to mind

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to add alpha channel to existing JPEG image and to render it in the browser: https://jim.studt.net/jpeg-alpha/.

Answer (score -2):

as far as is know JPEGs do not have the option of transparency. You need to use PNG or you have to fill in the virtual transparent content from underneath

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking. He wants to programatically take the jpeg data and create a mask for some of those pixels.

Comment: There should be a conversion, but the based image is JPEG